# Script allowing the modification of several values in a configuration file

Tags: shell

Hello developer friends,

I am looking to create a Shell script to modify several configuration files at several different paths.
For example; in /etc/nginx create a .bck file of the nginx.conf file and in the .conf file, replace the value "/etc/nginx/nginx-cloudflare.conf" with "/etc/nginx/nginx-cloudflare-2022.conf"

This manipulation would have to be done on several files and I would like to automate it as much as possible.

Do you have a script with an easy way to do it?

According to my research, it would be necessary to make a loop of conditions and the use of sed
I don't really know how it works, so I'm turning to you.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot comment yet due to reputation, but I was going to suggest exactly what you were thinking: create a bash shell `.sh` script https://www.w3schools.io/terminal/bash-tutorials/, make it executable with `chmod +x filename.sh` so you can run it like `./filename.sh`, and within it you can use `sed` https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sed.1.html in an in-place fashion `--in-place[=SUFFIX]` that also creates backups of said files. `Sed` search replace format is `'s/search/replace/flags'`.